# URL rewrite - odd url is produced

Tags: url-rewriting

My first attempt at doing an URL rewrite.
Usual scenario. Domain name seperate from host.
So I've changed the name servers and domain points to holding page at host so that's ok.
And purchased a domain pointer from the host to allow for a domain to be pointed at a sub folder.
Added the following code to web config file in root folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="xyz.uk" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?xyz.uk" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="\xyz\ {R:0}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite> 
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I get "The page isn't redirecting properly" and my url reads as "http://www.xyz.uk/%5Cxyz%5Cxyz/xyz/xyz/xyz/xyz/xyz/xyz/xyz/xyz/xyz/xyz/xyz/xyz/xyz/xyz/xyz/xyz/xyz/xyz/"

Googled this and all the examples I've seen are the same as the one I'm using.
Where am I going wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The actual code that works is below.

TIP.............I was helped on another forum and even though I made the changes, the page still wouldn't redirect.

PROBLEM WAS..........the browser cache was remembering the old redirect url!!

CLEAR DOWN your browser cache and any changes can then be seen immediately. Happened in Chrome and Firefox.

Correct code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="xyz.uk" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?xyz.uk" />
            <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/xyz/" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="xyz/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite> 
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```